# How to create a Flat Button in WinAPI with visual style

Tags: c++, winapi, button, visual-styles

I wanted to create a flat image push button like the Windows 7 mute button.

Here's the picture: [flat button](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2098541/temp/flat.jpg)

[image]

When mouse hover it(display border): [flat button hover](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2098541/temp/hover.jpg)

[image]

I tried to use BS_FLAT style, but nothing changed. My code is using visual style. When I try BS_FLAT without visual style, it does look flat, but still has a one pixel border.

So I want the button to look flat and without border, but when mouse hover it, it become a normal button. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create toolbar with one button. When creating use `TBSTYLE_FLAT` style. I think also you will need `CCS_NOPARENTALIGN | CSS_NORESIZE | CCS_NODIVIDER` style bits.

Comment: Where are those CSS_* styled you mentioned defined?